# serveo.net returning 502 when trying to tunnel localhost web api, front-end framework angular

Tags: javascript, angular, tunnel

I am having an issue with `serveo.net`.

I am trying to check if some Social media meta tags I introduced in my application will work properly, now I don't wish to finish a PR without being certain of the result. 
but since these meta tags can only be tested on a live server, I had the idea to tunnel my localhost and then check the results with https://opengraphcheck.com

my localhost is running on `"localhost:4500"`, and I am using following command in my terminal `"ssh -R 80:localhost:4500 serveo.net"`, this returns a URL however when I try to navigate to the URL presented by server I receive a

> HTTP ERROR 502.

What could be the cause of this?

I am using back-end WEP API project built in C# and a front-end Angular project. Angular Live Development Server is listening on `localhost:4500`

Comment: Have you find a solution about this issue?

Answer (score -1):

```
ssh -R 80:127.0.0.1:4500 serveo.net
```

Comment: Why? What would you like tested about that? What possible results could that experiment yield? Why? What would they mean? What would in each case be the solution to the problem? Please try for [answer].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).